# Choosing right data structure and design for Java multithreading problem

Tags: java, multithreading, data-structures

I am implementing a singleton class that must handle multiple threads accessing its data structure at once.

The class has a method that returns true if the data structure already contains myObject and false otherwise. If the object has not been seen then object is added to the data structure.

`boolean alreadySeen(MyObject myObject){}`

MyObject has two member variables `Instant expiration` and `String id` where `id` acts as my key to decide whether the data structure contains `myObject`.  **I cannot change MyObject class.** I need to periodically check the `expiration` of myObjects in the data structure and remove them if they have expired.

**So I am looking to use one or more data structures that I can quickly add, delete and search by both** `expiration` **and** `id`. *I will mostly be adding elements and searching if element exists with the periodic cleanup removing expired elements.*

A map like `ConcurrentHashMap<id,MyObject>` gives me the O(1) insert and delete but it would be O(n) to search through for expired objects.

As mentioned above I cannot change the MyObject class. So I thought about making a wrapper for that class so I can override equals() and hashcode() and then do an ordered set like `ConcurrentSkipListSet<MyObjectWrapper>(new ExpComparator())` This would let me order order the set by expiration date and then I could quickly find expired ones on top. However I believe this would be O(log n) for search, delete.

Is there any better structure I could use? And if not am I better off in the long run with the map at O(1) lookup and add but periodic O(n) for delete of expiration? Or better for set with O(log n) of everything?

Comment: Do you really need to actively expire? If there is no memory pressure, you can also expire/invalidate on the next lookup (which you most likely have to do anyway as cleanup is periodic and may be badly timed). And if you do need to expire on a regular background check, a full scan of the map every few seconds/minutes does not sound like a big performance issue. Also, there are open-source libraries that provide cache implementations that take care of these things.

Comment: @Thildo The periodic cleanup is for memory pressure. So does it sound like the map would be my best bet? Or can you throw some keywords my way for the open-source libraries?

Comment: @Thidlo To clarify I will only ever receive valid objects into my method `boolean alreadySeen(MyObject myObject){}`. So the objects passed in will never be expired so I cannot delete them at next lookup.

Answer (score 0):

You lookup，add and remove operation can run at O(1),but it need other cost as follow:

- First,it need double memory to store data
- Second,Expiration time cannot be very accurate

we need two map，one store object，key is the id and value is object，like `Map<id,MyObject>` another may to store the relationship between expiration and MyObjects like`Map<Long,List<MyObjects>>`,key need to calculate.

Codes:
In order to simple write code i modify your MyObject class:

```
class MyObject {
    private long expiration;
    private String id;
}
```

The other code
    private Map dataSet = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private Map> obj2Expiration = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

```
public boolean alreadySeen(MyObject myObject) {
    boolean exist = dataSet.containsKey(myObject.getId());
    if (!exist) {
        dataSet.put(myObject.getId(),myObject);
        Long expirateKey = myObject.getExpiration() / 5000;
        List<MyObject> objects = obj2Expiration.get(expirateKey);
        if (null == objects) {
            objects = new ArrayList<>();
            obj2Expiration.put(expirateKey,objects);
        } else {
            objects.add(myObject);
        }
    }
    return exist;
}

@Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
public void remove() {
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long needRemode = now /5000 -1;
    Optional.ofNullable(obj2Expiration.get(needRemode))
        .ifPresent(objects -> objects.stream().forEach(o -> {
            dataSet.remove(o.getId());
        }));
}
```